# How to load and play a list of audio files

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I have two View Controllers `collectionViewChild` and `imageViewController`. I load image in `imageViewController`. Now on that image I have a button I want to play a specific sound on each image. I know how to play a single audio sound but don't know how to select a specific sound and play it with the required image.

```
// collectionViewChild , here i want to display the image in the collectionviewChild



 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetailedImage", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){ if segue.identifier == "showDetailedImage" {
            let indexPaths =           self.collectionViewChild!.indexPathsForSelectedItems()!
            let indexPath = indexPaths[0] as NSIndexPath
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! imageViewController
             vc.title = self.tableData[indexPath.row]
            vc.image = images[indexPath.row] as! UIImage
           }}}
```

// This is ImageViewController

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class imageViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var imageView03: UIImageView!
    var selMake = UIImage()
  var image = UIImage()
     var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

// on this button i want to play the specific audio file
@IBAction func soundButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let soundLocation = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("2", ofType: ".mp3")
     do {
    self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: soundLocation!))
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    }
    catch {
    print("Something bad happened. Try catching specific errors to narrow things down")
    }
    self.audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    self.audioPlayer.play()
    }
    else { print("") }

override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.imageView03.image = self.image
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
```

Comment: you can create an array and map included object (audio )  with your image 
then when show each image with an index you can play objectAtIndex your image :)
or you can pass and set a property in your chilCollectionView then find the file from that property and play it :)

Comment: In the imageviewController each title value of image also comes from it ParentVC like var titleValue = String() , The title of the image and the sound i want to play is of same name so i am stuck with creating an array of the entire audio sounds and to play it through matching with the title of each image , can you provide me any materials regarding this issue

Answer (score 0):

Would a helper class with multiple audio players not help? I made a simple audio player class that's easily extendable for multiple tracks.

You can get my helper from gitHub
https://github.com/crashoverride777/Swift2-Music-Helper

When an image is pressed you play the corresponding sound in the button method.

```
Music.sharedInstance.playImage1()
Music.sharedInstance.playImage2()
```

...

You could combine this with Mohameds comment above.

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: In the imageviewController each title value of image also comes from it ParentVC like var titleValue = String() , The title of the image and the sound i want to play is of same name so i am stuck with creating an array of the entire audio sounds and to play it through matching with the title of each image , can you provide me any materials regarding this issue

Comment: I have been playing around with arrays of audio stuff recently but haven't really got it to work. Ill post some update for this if I get it sorted. Sorry

Comment: Thanks , i am waiting